# How to load external plugin (Owl Slider) in webpack?

Tags: javascript, slider

I use the OwlSlider2 (https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/) for my project.

Furthermore i use webpack, to build all my JSS and CSS files.

I load the owl.js directly in my website.

In my main.js i want to reference to owlCarousel but i get the following error:

```
uery.Deferred exception: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...)(...).owlCarousel is not a function TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...)(...).owlCarousel is not a function
```

My main.js doesn't find the function owlCarousel() in owl.js.

How i can pass the information of the external file to my main.js?